# "Sideload" an App for Office programatically on the Desktop

Tags: vsto, office365, office365-apps, office-js

I'm not sure whether "sideloading" is the correct term: Is therea an API to programatically install an Office Javascript API based add-in (e.g. a Task Pane app) in to the current / specific document on the desktop (at least on Windows)?

VisualStudio does this when you debug an App for Office project. How do I go about achieving the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no current way to programmatically insert an app (now "Office Add-in") into a document *via JavaScript*. It is a scenario that the product group is aware of, but it's not something we have yet.

You *can* insert an it via the Open XML SDK (which is actually how Visual Studio does this), but that would be .NET code running outside of the Office add-in (and not on the currently open document). Visual Studio in particular is atually inserting an app registered into the special local registry-based "Developer Store", but I can't think of any reason why wouldn't work for an actual Office-Store or SharePoint App Catalog-hosted app. If you are interested in going this route, let me know, and I might be able to find some pointers on the code you'd need to write.

Finally (though it probably goes without saying), you can insert an app into a Template, rather than a regular document. That way, anyone creating a document from that template would get your add-in -- I believe that's what the Paypal Invoicing add-in in Excel does, for example.

Hope this helps,

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, Developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: Thanks Michael! Doing it via .NET code is what we were after. We could also do the Template approach but, we wanted to have a way to convert existing docs to have the add-in inserted automatically. Please do point me to any samples available for the OpenXML SDK way of doing it.

Comment: The simplest way is probably to just create a document with the Office Add-in inserted within it, then run a tool that will analyze your document and generate the C# code you need to re-create such document.  Please see http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/04/open-xml-sdk-tool-to-analyse-documents-and-generated-c-code/, for a blog post that describes the process.  The tool itself is available at http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425.  Hope this helps!